# 2nd screen failure on Thinkpad running Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, thinkpad

I have a 6th Gen Lenovo X1C, running Fedora 32. Bought a nice external monitor (G-story) as a second display.

However, connecting the monitor over USB-C doesn't work. The screen is black, and Fedora does not recognize it. (Does not show up in lsusb or xrandr)

Some interesting observations:

- Monitor does not show up in xrandr
- Monitor does not show up in lspci
- There ARE some log entries when I plug in the second screen.

```
    Feb 20 09:17:55 x1c kernel: usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
    Feb 20 09:17:55 x1c kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1a40, idProduct=0801, bcdDevice= 1.00
    Feb 20 09:17:55 x1c kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
    Feb 20 09:17:55 x1c kernel: usb 1-4: Product: USB 2.0 Hub
    Feb 20 09:17:55 x1c kernel: hub 1-4:1.0: USB hub found
    Feb 20 09:17:55 x1c kernel: hub 1-4:1.0: 4 ports detected
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c kernel: usb 1-4.3: new full-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c kernel: usb 1-4.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2a94, idProduct=5249, bcdDevice= 1.03
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c kernel: usb 1-4.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c kernel: usb 1-4.3: Product: Multi-Touch by G2TSP
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c kernel: usb 1-4.3: Manufacturer: G2Touch
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c kernel: input: G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.3/1-4.3:1.0/0003:2A94:5249.0013/input/input37
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c kernel: hid-multitouch 0003:2A94:5249.0013: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.3/input0
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c kernel: hid-generic 0003:2A94:5249.0014: hiddev96,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.3/input1
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c mtp-probe[43176]: checking bus 1, device 20: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.3"
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c mtp-probe[43176]: bus: 1, device: 20 was not an MTP device
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP (/dev/input/mouse2)
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP (/dev/input/event17)
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (**) G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: Applying InputClass "evdev touchscreen catchall"
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (**) G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: Applying InputClass "libinput touchscreen catchall"
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP'
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c kernel: usb 1-4.3: USB disconnect, device number 20
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event17 13:81 fd 93 paused 0
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (**) G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: always reports core events
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event17"
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (II) event17 - G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (II) event17 - G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: device is a touch device
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (II) event17 - G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: device removed
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.3/1-4.3:1.0/0003:2A94:5249.0013/input/input37/event17"
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 14)
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (**) G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: (accel) selected scheme none/0
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (**) G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (**) G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (EE) client bug: Invalid path /dev/input/event17
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: [dix] couldn't enable device 14
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (EE) Couldn't init device "G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP"
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
    Feb 20 09:17:56 x1c /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3641]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:81
```

Does anybody know the correct configuration for this type of setup?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you might want to check out the diagrams on the g-story website. It's not indicated to work with PCs over USB-C. Just with phones. What does the manual say?

Comment: It worked perfectly when I had another linux distro on the same laptop.  Now that I'm running Fedora, it has stopped working.  So, fairly certain the distro is missing a driver or needs an extra config.